# type 1 error and size of the test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, error

In a lecture that I am attending, the lecturer refers to type I error probability $\alpha$ as "the size of the test" and $1-\beta$ as "power of the test". I have an intuition for the name power - it's like the power of rejecting correctly, but "size" is not making any sense to me. Could anyone explain why it is called so?

Comment: Just consider 'size' to be a _definition;_ That choice of the word to use must have been intuitive to someone, but need not be intuitive to you . // 'Size' amounts to Rejection rate when $H_0$ is true. At least 'size' takes up less space on a page than 'false rejection rate'.

Comment: @BruceET haha ok thanks!